# _.every function not evaluating correctly in Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js, lodash

I am iterating through an array of objects, what I would like to check is if all fields on all objects have had some input. When I run my code in the console with similar data it evaluates correctly but for some reason inside my vue component (in the watcher) it does not, why?

```
watch: {
    queryCopy: {
      handler(val){

        const something = every(this.queryCopy.rowData, (row) => every(row, (field) => field !==null));
        return something

      },
      deep: true
    }
  }
```

Here is an example of the data I am dealing with:

```
{"id":"query_4","rowData":[{"condition":null,"field":null,"operator":null,"name":null}]}
```

This evaluates to true! while all the values are `null`.
expected result to return `false` actual result is `true`

I am providing a sandbox where it actually works but still won't work in my project which is the same code!
https://codesandbox.io/s/2p54xypxwp

Comment: You can make a little example in a jsFiddle

Comment: I don't work much with JS, but can't you create a method that returns the first non-null element so that you can perhaps see what value is throwing this off?

Comment: Haven't had time to properly debug but did notice that adding immediate: true to the watcher has it returning true, then false, implying that something is changing to make the evaluation change.

Comment: Actually, it could be red herring, 
Lodash docs state:

This method returns true for empty collections because everything is true of elements of empty collections.

Comment: the thing is that this collection is not empty is has properties which are `null`